# How do you set the background-image of a GXT ContentPanel

Tags: gxt

Seriously, I would think this would be a simple thing, but I can't seem to get it figured out. I have a `ContentPanel` who's `Body` I want to set a background for using an `Image`? How do I do that?

BONUS QUESTION:
How do I change that image after the `ContentPanel` is rendered when a business action is triggered (e.g. user login).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what my problem was.  I know I tried this previously, but swore it wasn't rendering they way I wanted it to.

```
cp.setBodyStyle("background:black url('http://www.google.com/intl/en/adwords/select/images/samples/leaderboard.jpg') no-repeat top right");
```

I haven't figured out how to swap it after login yet since I think setBodyStyle can only be called pre-render.

The solution provided by @AbstractChaos could probably work, but there's a problem using the Image object with that.  Might need to incorporate the CssResource.

**UPDATE**
@see the answer provided by @gonella as well.  I no longer use GWT, so I haven't tested it.  If that answer gets enough votes, I will change the official answer for this question.

Answer (score 2):

I.e:

```
ContentPanel cp1 = new ContentPanel();

Image loadingImage = new Image(ExampleImages.INSTANCE.openstack01_580x200());
cp1.add(loadingImage);
```

---

```
public interface ExampleImages extends ClientBundle {

  public ExampleImages INSTANCE = GWT.create(ExampleImages.class);

  @Source("images/Openstack01_580x200.jpg")
  ImageResource openstack01_580x200();

}
```

It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the background up as a CSS style like so

```
.image1 {
background: url("yourLink");
}

.image2 {
background: url("another Link");
}
```

then possibly change the style it points to using

```
contentPanel.setBodyStyleName("image2");
```

as for your bonus question if in doubt call layout

```
contentPanel.layout(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in this way
contentPanel.setStyleAttribute("background","url('image link')");

When the business action is triggered then call this
contentPanel.setStyleAttribute("background","url('new image link')");

Comment: That doesn't work for ContentPanel.  To set the background for just the Body section, you have to get reference to that element.  See my answer for an example.